# Deserializing an object without having access to the class bytecode in Java

Tags: java, networking, serialization

I am trying to send a self-defined `serializable` object over a network socket and deserialize on the other side. Here is the definition of the class that I want to send:

```
public class Test implements implements Runnable, Serializable{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

I want to reconstruct this class on the other end without having access to the class `bytecode` just by casting it to `Runnable`. Unfortunately, it gives me `ClassNotFoundException` exception. Is there any workaround that I can deserialize the object without having access to the class `bytecode`?

Comment: Think about what you're asking. You want to be able to transport code over a network and then execute it, without having access to the code?

Comment: One way to think about it is to send a ".class" file over the network and execute it again.

Comment: What do you think a `.class` file contains, if not the bytecode?

Comment: Indeed it contains bytecode. I am wondering if serialization works based on bytecode. If so, I will be able to deserialize the object without having access to the source code. If it is true, my question is how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Not really. You can however supply the jars via an http server, and then run the client with the java.rmi.server.codebase system property set to a list of URLs from where RMI will load the classes.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are asking is not possible.

Java Serialization api sends the Data Fields inside an object and some housekeeping information. The data fields are sent in a compact form. On the receiver's side, the object is constructed back with these data field values.

Think of it as when you create an object normally and constructor initializes your fields. Here Java Serialization is doing the job of constructor but you still need the class definitions which contains bytecode for methods etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the classname from the message in the ClassNotFound exception. I wish there was a better way of getting the class name from a deserialised class without requiring the class being loaded.